# mutate(across(where())) call not working as expected

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data that looks like this and I'm trying to replace all the NA's with 0:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   area_fips NAME                    variable                                    estimate   moe percent
   <chr>     <chr>                   <chr>                                          <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 01001     Autauga County, Alabama Less than 9th grade                              909   235      NA
 2 01001     Autauga County, Alabama 9th to 12th grade, no diploma                   3364   520      NA
 3 01001     Autauga County, Alabama High school graduate (includes equivalency)    11880   665      NA
 4 01001     Autauga County, Alabama Some college, no degree                         7663   648      NA
 5 01001     Autauga County, Alabama Associate's degree                              3323   505      NA
 6 01001     Autauga County, Alabama Bachelor's degree                               6320   607      NA
 7 01001     Autauga County, Alabama Graduate or professional degree                 4401   558      NA
 8 01001     Autauga County, Alabama Less than 9th grade                               NA    NA      NA
 9 01001     Autauga County, Alabama 9th to 12th grade, no diploma                     NA    NA      NA
10 01001     Autauga County, Alabama High school graduate (includes equivalency)       NA    NA      NA
```

Trying to use the newish `dplyr` syntax and it doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = everything(), ~ replace(., is.na(.), 0)))

data %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ replace(., is.na(.), 0)))

data %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.na), ~ replace(., is.na(.), 0)))
```

After doing some research, using `replace(is.na(.), 1` is probably a better way to do this, but I'm still perplexed why the above isn't working.

Here's the `dput` of the data:

```
structure(list(area_fips = c("01001", "01001", "01001", "01001", 
"01001", "01001", "01001", "01001", "01001", "01001"), NAME = c("Autauga County, Alabama", 
"Autauga County, Alabama", "Autauga County, Alabama", "Autauga County, Alabama", 
"Autauga County, Alabama", "Autauga County, Alabama", "Autauga County, Alabama", 
"Autauga County, Alabama", "Autauga County, Alabama", "Autauga County, Alabama"
), variable = c("Less than 9th grade", "9th to 12th grade, no diploma", 
"High school graduate (includes equivalency)", "Some college, no degree", 
"Associate's degree", "Bachelor's degree", "Graduate or professional degree", 
"Less than 9th grade", "9th to 12th grade, no diploma", "High school graduate (includes equivalency)"
), estimate = c(909, 3364, 11880, 7663, 3323, 6320, 4401, NA, 
NA, NA), moe = c(235, 520, 665, 648, 505, 607, 558, NA, NA, NA
), percent = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The first two work for me (replaced the NA with zero), the third is a syntax error. Maybe it's version numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `replace_na`, which simplifies the job greatly:

```
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ replace_na(., 0)))
# A tibble: 10 × 6
   area_fips NAME                    variable                                    estimate   moe percent
   <chr>     <chr>                   <chr>                                          <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 01001     Autauga County, Alabama Less than 9th grade                              909   235       0
 2 01001     Autauga County, Alabama 9th to 12th grade, no diploma                   3364   520       0
 3 01001     Autauga County, Alabama High school graduate (includes equivalency)    11880   665       0
 4 01001     Autauga County, Alabama Some college, no degree                         7663   648       0
 5 01001     Autauga County, Alabama Associate's degree                              3323   505       0
 6 01001     Autauga County, Alabama Bachelor's degree                               6320   607       0
 7 01001     Autauga County, Alabama Graduate or professional degree                 4401   558       0
 8 01001     Autauga County, Alabama Less than 9th grade                                0     0       0
 9 01001     Autauga County, Alabama 9th to 12th grade, no diploma                      0     0       0
10 01001     Autauga County, Alabama High school graduate (includes equivalency)        0     0       0
```